# So what is the everypage package replacement?

Tags: everypage

I'm getting a warning that the everypage package is now in legacy status due to similar functionality provided by LaTeX.  Great, what is it?

Comment: Note that `everypage` will still work in newer releases, so `\usepackage{everypage}` then `\AddEverypageHook` should work regardless of the LaTeX release

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can now add to the hook `shipout/background`, which does the same job:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook {shipout/background}{\put (1in,-1in){Hello world!}}
\begin{document}

Text 

\newpage

Test

\end{document}
```

(If you `\show` the `\AddEverypageHook` command after the update, this is exactly what it now does.)

Comment: Found the docs in base/lthooks-docs  You had me worried with \put.

Comment: I'm getting this warning even though I do not specifically call it myself. Something else is calling it. Now what? (edited: I think it might be the package `background` calling it)