# Solving everypage warning

Tags: warnings, everypage

**Functionality similar to this package has recently(everypage) been implemented in LaTeX. This package is now in(everypage) legacy status.**

I am getting this error everytime I run my programme. I have checked that my Texstudio is finely updated. To avoid this error, I tried to use `\usepackage{silence}` but then I get the warning File **`silence.sty' not found. \usepackage** and the required file could not be found while downloading the package.  I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573329/so-what-is-the-everypage-package-replacement) but it is not working.

It is not causing any problem in my programme but it is quite awkward to bear this warning whole of the time.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\backgroundsetup{contents=Manjoy Das, opacity=0.2,color=black}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8289}{}
\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

After running this, the warnings are

1. Functionality similar to this package has recently(everypage) been implemented in LaTeX. This package is now in(everypage) legacy status.
2. You appear to be running a version of LaTeX(everypage) providing the new functionality.

In my opinion, something happened in this.

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
            $$ & & & & &\text{row numbers}\\
            $w'x'y'z$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$(1)$\\
            $w'x'yz'$ & $0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$(2)$ \\ \cline{2-5}
            $w'x'yz$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$(3)$ \\
            $wx'yz'$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$(4)$ \\
            $wxy'z'$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$(5)$ \\ \cline{2-5}
            $wx'yz$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$(6)$\\
            $wxyz'$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$(7)$ \\   
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

because after this table, all texts are coloured in green which usually happens within `$...$` mode.

Comment: Do you load the `everypage` package? If not, make a full but minimal  example that shows this problem.

Comment: @daleif I have edited my question

Comment: this errors as \backgroundsetup is undefined. Beside this: simply remove everypage, it is not needed anymore.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well then how to solve it?

Comment: I used `\usepackage{background}` in the preamble which I forgot to mention.

Comment: Why don't you simply do want the warning tells you and remove \usepackage{everypage} from your document and look what happens?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it shows same warning after removing `\usepackage{everypage}`. At first I did not use it. But when the error occurred, I used `\usepackage{everypage}` but still same warning is showing up.

Comment: the background package forces the loading of everypage. So write the author that he should update his package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how do I do this? This is not true. Because after removing `\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=text, opacity=0.2,color=black}`, I am getting the same error.

Comment: unreleated but don't do this `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`  utf8 has been the default for some years.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok.. But is there any solution for this everypage error?

Comment: @ManjoyDas as Ulrike says, it is not an error simply a warning. The solution is not to load `everypage` so if you are using a package that uncoditionally loads everypage either don't use that package if the warning bothers you, or  contact the maintainer of teh package and ask that it be updated.

Comment: or make a local renamed copy of background package and remove everypage from that