# How to include page number at the top right hand corner 1 cm from top and 1 cm from right edge?

Tags: margins, page-numbering, book-class

I am using book class.
My margins have to be 3cm at top, bottom, left, right.
The code I have right now is this:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} %for margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for page number
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

This gives me accurate margins and places the page number at the top right, but not in the proper place as specified. Thank you for your help!

Comment: All the related questions are slightly more complicated, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663351/placement-of-page-number-when-page-is-rotated-plus-warning/663420?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C38.1489#663420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Using the `tikz` package it is possible to position material using absolute page coordinates, regardless of the geometry used for the text.

It only requires a single line (`\node at ...`) to position the page number  at certain distance from the top and left of the  upper right  corner of the page (named `current page.north east`).

(Strictly speaking it will position the center of the box containing the page number).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 

%\newgeometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=3cm, showframe}%USE TEST the numpber position <<<
    
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for page number
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node at ([xshift=-1cm, yshift=-1cm] current page.north east){\thepage};}
    
\usepackage{tikz}% ****** added <<<<

\begin{document}
     Some words.        
\end{document}
```

Uncomment

```
\newgeometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=3cm, showframe}
```

to test the correct placement of the page number.

[image: b]

**(2)** A similar result is obtained with the `eso-pic` package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 

%\newgeometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=3cm, showframe}%USE TEST the numpber position <<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for page number
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{}

% ************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{eso-pic}    

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \put(\paperwidth-1cm,\paperheight-1cm)
    {\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\thepage}}}
}
% **************

\begin{document}
     Some words.        
\end{document}
```

**(3)** And the **simplest** solution, without additional packages  using the recent macro `\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 

%\newgeometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=3cm, showframe}%USE TEST the numpber position <<<

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put(\paperwidth-1cm,-1cm){% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\thepage}}
}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for page number
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{}

     
\begin{document}
Some words.
\end{document}
```