# How to make a dotted vertical line with \twocolumn?

Tags: two-column, parcolumns, dotfill, setlength

My code creates a vertical line between the two columns, but I'm not sure how to make it dotted.

````
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[width = 18cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{choice}
\setcounter{choice}{1}

\newcommand{\tikzhead}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-2.7cm, xshift=-1cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path[draw=none, fill=lightgray] (2,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,2cm);
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}
\clearscrheadings
\ihead{\tikzhead{\headmark}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newenvironment{question}{%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\thequestion}}}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{\phantom{\rule{\columnwidth-1.9em-\columnsep}{\heightof{1}}}}\par
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\rightmargin{1em}%
    \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
    \setlength\labelsep{0pt}}%
    \item[]}%
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{choices}{%
  \begin{list}{\Alph{choice})}{%
    \setlength\labelwidth{30pt}%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\labelsep{10pt}%
    \usecounter{choice}}}%
  {\end{list}}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}



\twocolumn
\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Welcome! I can't get this to compile without error. You haven't specified a class and you're using conflicting packages. This surely gives you errors when you try to compile it!

Comment: Also nesting `tikzpicture`s is unsupported and very likely to cause weird bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `\AddToHook` and tikzpagenodes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}% also loads tikz
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[width = 18cm, headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{choice}
\setcounter{choice}{1}

\newsavebox{\headbox}
\savebox{\headbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw=none, fill=lightgray] (2,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
%\geometry{headheight=\ht\headbox}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}% ???

\newenvironment{question}{%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\thequestion}}}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{\phantom{\rule{\columnwidth-1.9em-\columnsep}{\heightof{1}}}}\par
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\rightmargin{1em}%
    \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
    \setlength\labelsep{0pt}}%
    \item[]}%
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{choices}{%
  \begin{list}{\Alph{choice})}{%
    \setlength\labelwidth{30pt}%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\labelsep{10pt}%
    \usecounter{choice}}}%
  {\end{list}}
%\setlength\columnseprule{0.5pt}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node at (current page header area.center) {\usebox\headbox};
  \draw[dotted] (current page text area.north) -- (current page text area.south);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}



\twocolumn
\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never heard of \AddToHook. I'll read up on it!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573329/so-what-is-the-everypage-package-replacement?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C76.5414

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of questionable code in your post and I've only done a very minimal cleanup. Regarding your actual question, it is probably easiest to set the column separator to `0pt` in width and just add the dashed line with `tikz`, since you're using that anyway.

I've made the following assumptions:

- that you're using `scrarticle` (since you're loading Koma packages);
- that you're using A4 paper (ditto);
- that you nonetheless want American hyphenation patterns (since you're explicitly loading this unless you configured your system differently);
- that `scrlayer-scrpage` matters more to you than `fancyhdr`;
- that you may or may not actually want `geometry` given everything else going on;
- that you have no other reason for loading `enumitem` since you're not using it here;
- that you are not filling your document with filler text for some reason and don't need `blindtext`.

Then the following produces a dashed rule as column separator, compiles without error and avoids nesting `tikzpicture`s.

```
\documentclass[american,a4paper]{scrarticle}% or something?
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% american, presumably
% \usepackage{blindtext} % unused, unnecessary
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
% \usepackage{xcolor} % loaded by tikz
% \usepackage{fancyhdr} % incompatible with scrlayer-scrpage
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[width = 18cm]{geometry}% shouldn't be used with scrlayer-scrpage/koma classes if at all possible 
% \usepackage{enumitem} % unused
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{choice}
\setcounter{choice}{1}

\newcommand{\tikzhead}[1]{% avoid nesting tikzpictures
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path[draw=none, fill=lightgray] ([yshift=-2.7cm, xshift=1cm]current page.north west) coordinate (lr) rectangle ++({\paperwidth-2cm},2cm);
    \draw [dashed] (current page text area.north) -- (current page text area.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles % replace deprecated macro
\ihead{\tikzhead{\headmark}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newenvironment{question}{%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\thequestion}}}%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{\phantom{\rule{\columnwidth-1.9em-\columnsep}{\heightof{1}}}}\par
\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\rightmargin{1em}%
    \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
    \setlength\labelsep{0pt}}%
  \item[]}%
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{choices}{%
  \begin{list}{\Alph{choice})}{%
      \setlength\labelwidth{30pt}%
      \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
      \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
      \setlength\labelsep{10pt}%
      \usecounter{choice}}}%
  {\end{list}}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

\twocolumn
\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 3?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 4?
  \begin{choices}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 5
    \item 6
  \end{choices}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  What is 1 + 2?
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Note that

- `enumitem` would make your life easier, if you used it;
- inserting explicit spacing should be a last resort and certainly not a frequent occurrence;
- that inserting large amounts of rigid space tends to produce poor page-breaking;
- I cannot currently produce images of output worth diddly-squat.

[My attempt to produce an image didn't even show the damn line --- never mind that it is now dashed.]

Comment: Hi! Apologies for only responding now. Thank you so much for this. I'm very new to LaTeX and have to learn as I make things in real time. So everything is very messy and I'm only half-understanding things for now. I really appreciate your help!